# Wordpress MU: Newly uploaded theme is not showing in the theme page for actication

Tags: wordpress

I have uploaded a theme in the theme folder of my clients server. He has already provided me the admin access but when I go to the theme page I could not see my newly uploaded theme and for this reason I could not able to activate the theme. I'm waiting for your quickest help. I like to inform you have I have developed the theme on wordpress.org software not in wpmu.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone to the Themes Admin and enabled the theme?  (yoursite.com/wp-admin/wpmu-themes.php)

Comment: This is correct, and in WP 3 you can find it here: http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/network/themes.php

Answer (score 0):

I know default Wordpress only, but I guess the steps are the same:

- Check whether the template has actually been uploaded, using a FTP program
- Check whether it resides in the actual folder and not a subfolder as it happens often when you unzip packages
- Check whether the index file is intact and bears the correct markings, style.css is preset etc.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the WP default theme or another theme for a second and then switch back to the theme you want; it's a common problem issue with WP that themes sometimes don't show up right away.